# Project management and interference

Tags: project-management, saas

I am managing a software project that is hot for the company in terms of it being one of the things that is their bread & butter and it is going well.  I have another manager at the company interfering with my project and people.  How does one get this interference to go away.  One thought that he is not creative enough to create work, I mean there is a lot he can do in other aspects of the business that would make a huge impact.  The other piece of this is tasking a person that for a lack of a better way to describe it doesn't actually produce or actually make anything.  How does one handle or manage people that don't produce anything I guess is the question.

Would anyone have resource suggestions such as:
 - Books
 - Paid Training
 - Others

Maybe this is not a topic for this forum. :)  If so, suggestions for other forums would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about [pm.se] instead of programming or coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens a lot this kind of interference in the project. Your authority as a project manager depends upon the managerial structure in your company.

Some companies works only as functional teams and the project manager has little power and authority facing the different interests among the stakeholders. The PM is hierarchically under a functional area and reports to a functional manager instead of a program or portfolio manager.

On the other extreme side there is a project organizational structure, the project manager has control and authority on the project as well as on the teams.

The midst of these two structures is the matrix organization structure. In this case the project manager divides the responsibility to a functional manager.

I believe that your first step is to understand the power structure in your company works and how your hole is related to it. The next step is to assure exactly the role of the other manager who interferes in your management activities. Does he a client? Does he the sponsor? Or does he only a partner?

The stakeholder management is a daily activity in the PM job too. It is common to see this kind of interference from the stakeholders but always remember that the project manager is you.